# Working with arrays of mixed data types in f#

Tags: f#

I have a version of a function that works fine but with a tuple of different data types

I want to use this from excel though which means when I pass data to the function I can only use arrays of doubles or object. Because I have varius data types I upcast them all to object and then I rewrote this and made use of unboxing:

```
let returnvect (data:obj[][]) (dtsvec:float[]) (inputdate:float) =
let nrhrs = dtsvec |> Array.length
let itera = nrhrs - 1
let res = Array.zeroCreate nrhrs 
let resp = Array.zeroCreate nrhrs
for i=0 to itera do
    for a in data do
        match a.[0] with
        | r when unbox<float> r <= inputdate ->
            match a.[2] , a.[3] with
            | s, t when unbox<float> s <= dtsvec.[i] && unbox<float> t >= dtsvec.[i] -> 
                    res.[i] <- res.[i] + unbox<float> a.[4] 
                    resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + unbox<float> a.[5]  * unbox<float> a.[4] 
            |_ -> 
                res.[i] <- res.[i] + 0.0
                resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + 0.0
        |_ -> 
            res.[i] <- res.[i] + 0.0
            resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + 0.0
let avgprice = dotdivideZ resp res
let inp = [|dtsvec; res; avgprice|]
let newres = MultiArray inp
newres
```

It passes the type check but I get the following error when I run it:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
 at FSI_0044.returnvect(Object[][] data, Double[] dtsvec, Double inputdate)
```

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you write the calculation using fully typed representation and then just convert the result to object array for Excel? That way, most of your code would be fully typed and you'll get the usual benefits of F# (like avoiding casting exceptions)

Comment: yes, I guess. But my question then is how do I prepare the input, when it just comes as an obj[,] even though one column might really be a double, int or string? You are right though, a lot of the beauty of f# seems lost in this example

Comment: @TomasPetricek: I had another look at this and I cant really find a way around this. As soon as you use the function from another sytem / language you are bound by its limitations. Are you not? So if I pass the data from c# data either is an obj[,] or you have to pass many arrays and then they can be of different types, same goes for excel. Only data that comes from f# can have mixed type tuples. Or is that wrong? THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was the array of arrays. 
This works:

```
let returnvect (data:obj[,]) (dtsvec:float[]) (inputdate:float) =
    let itera = dtsvec |> Array.length
    let iterb = data.GetLength 0
    let res = Array.zeroCreate itera 
    let resp = Array.zeroCreate itera
    for i=0 to (itera - 1) do
       for j=0 to (iterb - 1) do
        match data.[j,0] with
        | r when unbox<float> r <= inputdate ->
            match data.[j,2] , data.[j,3] with
            | s, t when unbox<float> s <= dtsvec.[i] && unbox<float> t >= dtsvec.[i] -> 
                    res.[i] <- res.[i] + unbox<float> data.[j,4] 
                    resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + unbox<float> data.[j,5]  * unbox<float> data.[j,4] 
            |_ -> 
                res.[i] <- res.[i] + 0.0
                resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + 0.0
        |_ -> 
            res.[i] <- res.[i] + 0.0
            resp.[i] <- resp.[i] + 0.0
let avgprice = dotdivideZ resp res
let inp = [| dtsvec; res; avgprice |]
let newres = MultiArray inp
newres
```